# To center the row in card

Tags: flutter, center, card

hello i am unable to center the row in a card by using crossaxisalignment even
if i cover the row with center widget kindly help...

```
 Card(
        elevation: 4.0, // Card elevation
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), // Padding inside the card
            child: Row(
                

              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, // Align children in the middle vertically
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Following',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '5000',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Following',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '5000',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Following',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '5000',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not very explanatory and is a little confusing, do you want them to be aligned in the center Vertically or Horizontally?

Comment: i want the row to come at center vertically

Answer (score 0):

By adding mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, in columns you should achieve your results.

```
Card( elevation: 4.0, // Card elevation
            child: Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), // Padding inside the card
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, // Align children in the middle vertically
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Following',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '5000',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Following',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '5000',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Following',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '5000',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )))
```